# Что происходит если не вызывать конструктор базового класса?

Tags: python

Предположим я наследуюсь, но при этом не вызываю конструктор базового класса из потомка.

```
class Human:
    def __init__(self, sex):
        self.sex = sex
        print("Parent")
    def say():
        print("say")

class Man(Human):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Child")

m = Man()
m.say()
```

Что при этом происходит? Как я понимаю методы родителя не будут вызываться? И это все? Или еще что-то есть?

Comment: Метод say Man есть, но он считает, что есть один аргумент. Это self потомка?

Comment: Это означает, что сначала методы ищутся в классе str, затем в basestring, а уже потом - в object.

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka откуда тут str и basestring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поиск методов будет происходить сначала в классе объекта, потом в родительском. Это в простом случае. В Python есть множественное наследование, а иерархии классов могут представлять из себя довольно нетривиальные графы. Для разруливания таких случаев (mro, порядок разрешения методов) в Python применяется алгоритм C3. На хабре есть отличная [статья](https://m.habrahabr.ru/post/62203/)

В вашем случае вызовется метод родительского класса, но в объекте класса Man атрибут sex доступен не будет.

От себя добавлю - хорошей практикой, и признаком хорошей архитектуры, является вызов родительских методов внутри перопределенных.

Comment: а можете пояснить фразу "вызов родительских методов внутри перопределенных". Это как и зачем нужно? Типа как перегрузка в других языках?

Comment: Как виртуальные методы в других языках. Просто в Python все методы виртуальные по умолчанию. Нужно это чтобы не замещать реализацию родительского класса, а расширять. Можно конечно полностью перекрывать метод, но как я уже писал очень часто это значит, что класс не очень удачно спроектирован